# Confusion over Heroku Pricing on Hobby and Professional(Standard 1x)

Tags: heroku

**My goal is to run 2 workers and 1 web under 14 USD.** 
or **Can I run multiple processes under same dyno and is it a good production practice(n.b: I have a high traffic site)?.** (this seems like only way to keep it under 14 USD)

I have a Procfile defined like below:

```
web: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5004 server:engine --preload --log-file=- --log-level DEBUG -w 4
worker: python3 -u _worker.py
```

This is running on a **Heroku hobby server($7)** and for two processes, two dynos it cost me 7+7 = 14 USD.
[image]

Now if you look at the Professional(Standard 1x) Pricing it just cost me 25 USD for each dyno here.
[image]

But clearly, in the Heroku pricing section, it is written that **Unlimited background workers from Standard1x**. [Check the last Point of Standard Dyno Pricing](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) What does this even mean? Does it just mean I can scale but I gotta pay for each one or Is it like **I can start multiple workers in a single Dyno to keep it 25 USD**?.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this in the end? I'm similarly confused over the Standard 1x pricing description. It looks like workers require their own Dyno @ $25 each.

Answer (score 1):

A separate Dyno is required for each additional worker process. The wording on the Heroku's pricing page is a little misleading.

[image]

I queried it with support and they clarified:

> In this context, "unlimited background workers" means you can run as
> many worker processes as you need to. On the lower tiers(free and
> hobby), the number of worker processes that can be used is limited.
>
> However, Heroku is built on a 1-process-per-dyno model, which means
> every worker needs to run on its own dyno. So you will be charged for
> 1 dyno for each worker process you use. To say it a different way,
> it's not "unlimited worker processes for $25/mon", but instead it's
> "run unlimited worker processes at $25/mon each".

Basically, the Free tier can have up to 2 dynos, Hobby can have up to 10 and the Production tiers can have as many as you want ... but you'll pay for each dyno :)